# Nodejs > A Class imported at two places - works at one place and not at another

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, webdriver-io

Project Background:
Technology: NodeJs, Webdriverio, Mocha, Chai, (configured ECMA6 in IDE)
—————— 
File: product-page.js

```
var/let Component = require(‘./component.js’);

Class ProductPage{

    constructor(productType){
        this. productType = productType;
    }

    getFirstProduct(){
        return new Component(first);
    }
}

module.exports = {

    ProdPage : function(pType){
        if(pType === "type"){
            return new ProductPage(type);
        }else {
            return new ProductPage();
        }
    }

};
```

—————— 
File: component.js

```
var/let ProductPage = require(‘./product-page.js’). ProdPage;

Component(){

    constructor(comp){
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    action(){ //some action; return this; }

    clickToListProducts(type){
        return new ProductPage(aType); // This line does not returns ProdutPage, Error: ProductPage is not a function
    }
}

module.exports = Component;
```

—————— 
File: sample.js

```
var/let ProductPage = require(‘./product-page.js’). ProdPage;

SampleTest(){

    describe(){
     it(){
        SignInPage.signin();
        ProductPage()
            . getFirstProduct(first)
            .action()
            . clickToListProducts(sometype) // receives error from component page
    }
    }

}
```

——————

Here Product Page imported at SampleTest class works fine, But Product Page imported at Component is not recognized.

But following code works fine, hence i confirmed ProductPage accepts both no-arguments and single arguments

```
 it(){

    SignInPage.signin();
    ProductPage()
        . getFirstProduct(first)
        .action()
    ProductPage(sometype) // works fine
}
```

I have tried different combination of exporting and importing, but could not find solution.

Comment: `Var` is not a reserved word in JavaScript, `var` is, even if something is allowing you to run it lime this, don't do it, it's not a capital V

Comment: Upper case V was typo error, corrected it. I used 'let' as well. Both var and let works fine.

Comment: Remove the `new` in Component. You use `new` only on constructors -- only on `Class ProductPage`. Since the exported `ProdPage` function is not a constructor (even though its name confusingly starts with uppercase) you should not use `new`

Comment: Are you sure this even runs? product-page requires component but component requires product-page. This is not allowed in node.js and that is the real source of the error. Node.js (and javascript in general) does not support circular dependency and that is a good thing

Comment: @slebetman - Thank you for pointing out circular dependency, i ll read more about it...
I am also suspecting the same, about the way object were created. For now i resolved it by avoiding clickToListProducts method to provide new productList. Instead at Test it invokes Object twice.

    ProductPage()
                . getFirstProduct(first)
               .action();
     ProductPage(sometype)
               . doSomeOtherAction();